# ¿Cómo obtener la ruta de un archivo en la vista de un proyecto MVC .Net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, .net

Me gustaría obtener la ruta de un archivo para posteriormente subirla a mi servidor. Tengo un botón en las Vistas tal que :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Imagen, new { htmlAttributes = 
new { @class = "input", @type = "file" }
```

Es problema es que en el controlador obtengo únicamente el nombre del archivo y necesito la ruta completa. Según he investigado esto es debido a que los navegadores modernos no lo permiten por seguridad. En ese caso, ¿cuál sería la forma valida de obtener la ruta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma correcta de recibir un archivo no radica en que conozcas su ruta, sino en la forma en que el navegador la envía al servidor, que básicamente son bytes.

Para lograr eso necesitas marcar tu forma con el tipo de codificación:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <label for="file">Upload Image:</label>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Imagen, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "input", @type = "file" }
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" />
}
```

Y en tu método de acción (ActionMethod), recibir el archivo respectivamente, por ejemplo:

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase Imagen)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
            byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();
            ...
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("actionname", "controller");
}
```